# In java selenium, can we paste a string using clipboard action

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Need to paste a string value to a WebElement using Clipboard action

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(textValue);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
    fxDriver.findElement(textmessageplace).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.INSERT);
```